# how to access directory list in android

Tags: android

i want to access the directory structure in my application

Comment: So, what's your problem? What have you already written? Where are you stuck? Do you have any errors, is something not working as expected?

Comment: i want to see all the folders & file of my SDcard in android

Answer (score 1):

try

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File mfile=new File("/sdcard/");
File[] list=mfile.listFiles();

System.out.println("list"+mfile.listFiles().length);
for(int i=0;i<mfile.listFiles().length;i++)
{
   System.out.println("hidden path files.."+list[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
}
```

try this